# Can I resume backing up in Time Machine on my Mac?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, time-machine

I'm in the process right now of creating a backup in Time Machine, but I don't think I have enough time to fully make the back up.

If I cancel now (Press the little X button next to the "Backing up x amount of files"), can I resume it later or will I have to start all over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll be able to resume it later, though it'll take Time Machine a little while for it to figure out where it left off, especially if this is the initial backup of your entire computer.

Time Machine does its backups into a folder that has a date and time followed with "inProgress". Only once it's finished copying things does it move that folder into a normal backup - i.e. just a date and time.